# Load huge sql dump to mySql

Tags: mysql

I have a huge mysql dump file generated from phpmyAdmin (150 000 lines of create table, inserts....)

The mySql query tool fails to open such a big file.
As a result i can't insert all the records.

Is there a way to do this ?
Thanks
John

Comment: Is it the command line 'mysql' tool that fails to load the file? Usually something like mysql -p -h DBSERVER dbname  < dbname.sql should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to restore large mysql database from sql dump file is using unix/linux shell command.
To restore mysql database from a dump file, just type the command below:

```
mysql -u #username# -p #database# < #dump_file#
```

Of course you need to replace #username# to your database username and #database# to your target database. and rename #dump_file# to your dump file file name (Ex: dump.sql) Once you enter the command, the linux/unix shell will prompt you for your database user password, just key in your database password and you are done

borrowed from: http://www.techiecorner.com/31/how-to-restore-mysql-database-from-sql-dump-file/

Answer (score 0):

Split the file by parts. First the CREATE instructions, then the inserts.

Comment: i can't even open the file with notepad ++! I was wondering if a tool could read line by line..